# How to select an integer from a list and assign it in Python

Tags: python, list, indexing

Okay, I have a list in Python that I want to rotate around but also have a certain integer assigned to it. My question is how to obtain a certain index from a list and assign that number to a variable. The points I am referring to are the "THIS DOESN'T WORK". When I run this I get: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable. I can't figure out a way to assign that certain index to a variable. Please Help.

```
entryway1 = ['another locked door', 'a hallway-1', 'a hallway-2', 'a room']
came_from = ['right', 'left', 'forward', 'backward']
room_number = [1, 2, 3, 4]


def rotate_number(room_list, n): #This function rotates/shifts the room number values 
    room_list = (room_list[-n:] + room_list[:-n])
    return room_list


def rotate(list_1, n): #This function rotates/shifts the room sides values
    list_1 = (list_1[-n:] + list_1[:-n])
    return list_1


def room_1():  # This is one of four "rooms" surrounding the middle room
    global from_direction
    print("This is the locked door")
    from_direction = 'locked door'


def room_2():  # This is one of four "rooms" surrounding the middle room
    global from_direction
    print("This is hallway 1")
    from_direction = 'hallway 1'


def room_3():  # This is one of four "rooms" surrounding the middle room
    global from_direction
    print("This is hallway 2")
    from_direction = 'hallway 2'


def room_4():  # This is one of four "rooms" surrounding the middle room
    global from_direction
    print("This is a room")
    from_direction = 'room'


def look2():  # This is the middle room named the entryway.
    print("I must be in an entryway.")
    global entryway1
    global room_number
    global from_direction
    if from_direction == 'locked door':  # The four ifs check what direction you came from and sets the room up to that certain perspective through lists.
        entryway1 = rotate(entryway1, 3)
        room_number = rotate_number(room_number, 3)
    if from_direction == 'hallway 1':
        entryway1 = rotate(entryway1, 2)
        room_number = rotate_number(room_number, 2)
    if from_direction == 'hallway 2':
        entryway1 = rotate(entryway1, 1)
        room_number = rotate_number(room_number, 1)
    if from_direction == 'room':
        entryway1 = rotate(entryway1, 0)
        room_number = rotate_number(room_number, 0)
        print(entryway1)
```

This is the part I can't seem to work. Something with assigning an int from the list.

```
    room_number = 0
    movearea = True
    print("Where to go...")
    while movearea:    # This allows you to look around the room freely and sets a value according to what way you last looked at
        direction = input().lower()
        if direction == 'Look Right'.lower():
            print("*There is", entryway1[0], "there.*")  
            to_next_room = room_number[0]    # THIS DOESN'T WORK 
        if direction == 'Look Forward'.lower():
            print("*There is", entryway1[1], "there.*")  
            to_next_room = room_number[1]    # THIS DOESN'T WORK 
        if direction == 'Look Left'.lower():
            print("*There is", entryway1[2], "there.*") 
            to_next_room = room_number[2]    # THIS DOESN'T WORK 
        if direction == 'Look Back'.lower():
            print("*There is", entryway1[3], "there.*")  
            to_next_room = room_number[3]    # THIS DOESN'T WORK 

        if to_next_room == 0 and direction == 'open door': #the to_next_room checks what value was last assigned from looking at a certain direction. It also checks if you put in the right input to go to the next room.
            print('escape_game() was originally right')
            room_1()
        if to_next_room == 1 and direction == 'go there':
            print('forward1() was originally forward')
            room_2()
        if to_next_room == 2 and direction == 'go there':
            print('left1() was originally left')
            room_3()
        if to_next_room == 3 and direction == 'go there':
            print('emptyroom1() was originally back')
            room_4()
        else:
            pass


print("You are in a a locked door")  # This is a basic starting point for the game that this chunk of code is from.
room_3()   # This changes in the whole piece of code, but for testing I just 
type rooms 1-4 in here
next_room = input("would you like to move on?")
if next_room == 'yes':
    look2()
if next_room == 'no':
    print("ok bye")
else:
    pass
```

Comment: `room_number` is not a list

Comment: Why did you overwrite the value of `room_number`?: `room_number = 0`.

Comment: @ChristianDean I want the number to initially not be 1-4. I thought I needed to make it zero kind of like having a boolean false if I want to find it to be true in a loop. Do I not need it?

Answer (score 1):

You initially have:

```
room_number = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Then later you set:

```
room_number = 0
```

The second assignment is why you are getting the error message.